# How do I pass a click event along to other children below in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, bitmap

One of my decoration bitmaps covers up some important elements in my flex application. The problem is these elements become not clickable. How could make the bitmap not clickable or how could I pass the click event along to those children elements below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a common container for both the bitmap and the elements you need to access , since a bitmap is not clickable , the container itself needs to be clickable and listen to the mouse click event you need to dispatch, also make sure that:

```
    //"this" refers to the container
    this.mouseChildren = true;
```

The basic idea is that if your elements are in another container under the bitmap, the bitmap will act as a screen, if the elements are in the same container , the bitmap cannot screen the mouse events since the container itself is the EventDispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can set mouseEnabled = false on mx.controls.Image or whatever container the bitmap is loaded into.